# Introducing a new retrocomputing YouTube channel: Electronica Sovietica

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

Having checked self-promotion is OK here, I am writing to announce my new YouTube channel dedicated to my small but growing collection of Soviet retro computers and microcontrollers.

The first video introduces my four bit microcontroller kit and shows how it executes two lines of binary code.

Like, subscribe, share :-)

https://youtube.com/@ElectronicaSovietica

Comment: Looks cool! The "person with a camera, talking and pointing at things" style isn't all that common these days, but you make it work. Have you thought of putting your videos on PeerTube? [TILvids](https://tilvids.com/) is good for these kinds of video (non-boring educational); others are, of course, available.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip, I'll check it out!

Comment: Following the implication that my approach was old fashioned :-D I made short with the same machine: https://youtu.be/5Do4k9PSgzQ

Comment: What a lovely idea. But are you sure it's a good one?

Because now we demand **MORE**. Many more videos of many different machines or applications or languages or whatever you come up with! (Also, adding some canal in for would be nice. Likewise maybe a section list for videos onger than 2-3 minutes, so people not only see whats there but also can go forth and back without that stupid slider)

Comment: Oh, and I'm quite fine with the 'old fashioned' part. I do not need glossy AI effects, fancy voice over and so on, all I want is to see real computers and material and get factual information. Great vid.

Comment: Hey I'm super busy with work right now, but once work calms down I do want to produce MORE but it will generally be on a schedule of months rather than weeks/days :-)

Comment: Hey harlandski I just wanted to warn you that the link is dead. I fixed it up here, but just in case you posted the link anywhere else.

Comment: So, @harlandski, what are the chances of new content?

Comment: Good things come to those who wait :-D I'm on vacation right now and away from my Soviet electronics, but I plan to get back into making videos when I get back home :-)